# Test Class Issue Standard set Controller Class

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, standardsetcontroller

I write a test class to cover standard set controller class on account but i am not able to pass id. thats why not able cover code coverage.

here is my code

```
@IsTest
public class ClientReachEmailPageControllerTest {

    private static testMethod void test1() {
        User u = CreateOrder.createUser('testemail@emailmakerdetail.com', 'User Order Maker Details');
        insert u;

        // Create Client
        List<Account> acc= new List<Account>();
        Account client = new Account(LastName='TestAccount', personemail = 'test@test.com',Asst_Email__pc = 'test123@gmail.com');
        acc.add(client);
        Account client1 = new Account(LastName='TestAccount1', personemail = 'test@test.com',Asst_Email__pc = 'test123@gmail.com');
        acc.add(client1);

        //insert client;
        insert acc;

        // Create Order
        Order__c hOrder = CreateOrder.createHOrderItem(u.Id, u.Id, acc[0].Id, 'Test  Details');
        hOrder.Coat_Maker1__c ='a066YT000005c2vT';
        insert hOrder;        

        // Create Controller
        Test.startTest();       
        Test.setCurrentPage(Page.ClientReachEmailPage);
        ApexPages.StandardSetController stdSetController = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(acc);
        ClientReachEmailPageController obj = new ClientReachEmailPageController(stdSetController);  

        PageReference pageRef = Page.ClientReachEmailPage;        
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        Test.stopTest();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `StandardSetController`, you don't have to pass the ID, instead you will have to pass the list of records. You can set the records for `StandardSetController` using `setSelected` method. Below test class should cover your controller.

```
@isTest
public class ClientReachEmailPageControllerTest {
    private static testMethod void test1() {
        User u = CreateOrder.createUser('testemail@emailmakerdetail.com', 'User Order Maker Details');
        insert u;

        // Create Client
        List<Account> acc= new List<Account>();
        Account client = new Account(LastName='TestAccount', personemail = 'test@test.com',Asst_Email__pc = 'test123@gmail.com');
        acc.add(client);
        Account client1 = new Account(LastName='TestAccount1', personemail = 'test@test.com',Asst_Email__pc = 'test123@gmail.com');
        acc.add(client1);

        //insert client;
        insert acc;

        // Create Order
        Order__c hOrder = CreateOrder.createHOrderItem(u.Id, u.Id, acc[0].Id, 'Test  Details');
        hOrder.Coat_Maker1__c ='a066YT000005c2vT'; //If this is a relationship field, create a record for Coat Maker and assign the Id of that record to this field, if its a text field, it will work else the test class will fail.
        insert hOrder;        

        // Create Controller
        Test.startTest();       
        Test.setCurrentPage(Page.ClientReachEmailPage);
        ApexPages.StandardSetController stdSetController = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(acc);
        stdSetController.setSelected(acc);
        ClientReachEmailPageController obj = new ClientReachEmailPageController(stdSetController);  
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

**Note** : You should always add assert statements in your test class to check if your code is working as expected.

Comment: That hard-coded Salesforce Id looks like a problem waiting to happen. Is `Coat_Maker1__c` a Text field? I don't see how the unit test passes otherwise.

Comment: Yup, you are right @DavidReed, that test class would fail unless it is a text field. Added a comment.